# How to center get four pictures centered to one another (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and i'd like to get four pictures perfectally centered to one another with a space between them on one 100% height page. Do I need to use "img-responsive" ?
I'd like to have the four pictures in display on two rows, two columns with the same white space all around the pictures. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: http://www.bootply.com/TierSPlcaW

```css
.featured-work {
  height: 100%;
}
.row-work {
  height: 50%;
}
.row-work img {
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 30px;
}
.row-work {
  height: 50%;
}
.row-work img {
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-work">
  <div class="row row-work">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-work">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: instead of class="featured-work" try class="container"

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/TierSPlcaW

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need image responsive. I think instead of featured-work should be container instead

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-work">
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/">
                   </div>
                    </div>
                 <div class="row row-work">
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/">
                   </div>
                </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure u are using bootstrap because when I inspect the element it was not showing any bootstrap css added in head element.